# Gunzip the gzip data from context request body in golang

Tags: go, gzip, go-gin, gunzip, pako

I am working on a web app, in which i'm using golang [gin-gonic](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin) framework for creating rest api's, i want to read data from context body which is in gzip format, for gzipping the json data i'm using angular framework [pako](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pako) package,This package works pretty well and makes json data to gzip-compressed data. Now in my golang app i want to gunzip the gzipped data, for which i'm using the following-

i'm using [gzip](https://pkg.go.dev/compress/gzip) package.

in my router file i have added

```
router := gin.Default()
router.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))
```

I have made an Test function for this but there is error while reading the data

```html
func Test(c *gin.Context) {
    if c.GetHeader("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" {
        // Read the gzipped data from the request body
        gzippedBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "Failed to read request body")
            return
        }
        defer c.Request.Body.Close()
        buf := bytes.NewReader(gzippedBody)
        // Create a new reader for the gzip data
        reader, err := gzip.NewReader(buf)
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Failed to create gzip reader")
            return
        }
        defer reader.Close()

        // Read the decompressed data
        uncompressedBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Failed to read decompressed body")
            return
        }

        // Now uncompressedBody contains the decompressed data
        fmt.Println("Decompressed data:", string(uncompressedBody))

        // Handle the uncompressed data as needed
        // ...

        // Send a response
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Received and decompressed data successfully")
    } else {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "Expected gzipped data in request")
    }
    return
}
```

error is -> gzip: invalid header

Can anyone explain and let me know what needs to be corrected in order to get the desired result

Comment: If you're using the gzip middleware from gin, you should not unzip the body. It will be unzipped by the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

The gin gzip middleware can already handle this for you.  Here is the relevant test case:

https://github.com/gin-contrib/gzip/blob/master/gzip_test.go#L196C1-L219

Basically, just change

```
router.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression))
```

to

```
router.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression, gzip.WithDecompressFn(gzip.DefaultDecompressHandle)))
```